# Jacoco report aggregation plugin is not generating the XML file

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I'm working on a multi-module project that employs a standalone sub-project to aggregate coverage reports. The project is build using Gradle, employing the [Jacoco report aggregation plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) for Gradle.

Currently, the coverage report is generated in HTML format only. However, I specifically need the XML file format so that I can incorporate it into an artifact within Azure DevOps pipeline.

The root project and sub-projects have the following `build.grade` configuration files:

**Root project**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}   
sourceCompatibility = '17'
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }    
    tasks.withType(Test.class).tap {
        configureEach {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}
```

**One of the sub-projects**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}
dependencies {
   ...
}
```

**The standalone coverage sub-project**

```
 plugins {
   id 'java'     
   id 'jacoco-report-aggregation'
}
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
jar {
    enabled = false
}    
dependencies {
    jacocoAggregation project(':sub-project1')
    jacocoAggregation project(':sub-project2')  
  }
```

The root project `settings.gradle` file, just for completeness:

```
rootProject.name = 'my root project'
include 'sub-project1'
include 'sub-project2'
include 'coverage'
```

To generate the reports I'm using the following Gradle command:

```
> gradle clean build jacocoTestReport
```

In a different project with no sub-projects, I was able to generate the XML file by configuring up the Jacoco plugin report like this:

build.grade

```
jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    xml.required = true
    csv.required = false
}
```

Yet, I haven't be able to generate the XML format so far, for the multi-module project.

Any suggestions or clues wild be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions can be found in this [sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage_distribution.html) from the Gradle site.

The root and sub-projects `build.settigns` files are correct in my question.
But for the coverage project the `build.settings` is missing a dependency
The corrected file should be:

```
plugins {
   id 'java'     
   id 'jacoco-report-aggregation'
}
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
jar {
    enabled = false
}    
dependencies {
    jacocoAggregation project(':sub-project1')
    jacocoAggregation project(':sub-project2')  
}
//as in sample for the case you want to build the report when you run check
tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn tasks.named('testCodeCoverageReport', JacocoReport)
}
```

And to generate the aggregate report the command line should be:

```
$ ./gradlew testCodeCoverageReport
```

Note that invoking the task `jacocoTestReport` will not build the aggregate report.

The report will be generated at `<coverage project path>/build/reports/jacoco/testCodeCoverageReport`.

The XML file will also be generate there there. It's not necessary to enable CSV report format with the aggregate report plugin.

Comment: Do you happen to know where any of this is documented? [This was what I could find](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html). These steps are so simple and got things working for me, but outside of this SO post, I could not find a clear explanation of what is necessary to make this work.